# How to iteratively create class attributes for general tree?

Tags: python, object, tree, attributes

I'm learning about the general tree and binary tree data structures, using python as the learning medium.

I see that the binary tree class generally has three attributes, its value, left child and right child. And once this design choice is made, it doesn't require any changes.

The general tree, however, can have any number of children, bounded by 0 to infinity. So I'm curious, how can I create a variable number of children (for example `child_1`...`child_500`)?

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Perhaps each tree should have a children attribute, which is a list of values or a dictionary where the keys are the names child_1...child_500 and the values are their children..?

Comment: You're think about it the wrong way. If the number of children can vary, the class should have one attribute, like `children`, that's a `list` (or other container) of them. It would be very unwieldy to have to check for the existence of possibly an large number of named attributes.

Comment: _I see that the binary tree class_ What binary tree class? _Perhaps each tree should have a children attribute, which is a list of values_ martineau beat me to it, but yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, a variable amount of named attributes would become unwieldy. A list would a good idea. Personally, I recommend adapting the linked list architecture.

Define a GeneralTreeNode class and define the attributes as value, parent, child, left_sib and right_sib. You can think of the leftmost sibling as the "first born" (this is because it will be referenced as the *only* child of its parent node. All other siblings can be accessed by traversing from the leftmost sibling.

This little example shows how to make such a class, set values and relationships between nodes, and traverse from the root to the right most child of a small, three-node tree.

Hope this helps!

```
class GeneralTreeNode():

def __init__(self,value=None,parent=None,child=None,left_sib=None,right_sib=None):
    self.value = value
    self.parent = parent
    self.child = child
    self.left_sib = left_sib
    self.right_sib = right_sib

def get_value(self):
    return self.value

def get_parent(self):
    return self.parent

def get_child(self):
    return self.child

def get_left(self):
    return self.left_sib

def get_right(self):
    return self.right_sib   

def set_parent(self,parent):
    self.parent = parent

def set_child(self,child):
    self.child = child

def set_left(self,left_sib):
    self.left_sib = left_sib

def set_right(self,right_sib):
    self.right_sib = right_sib


a1 = GeneralTreeNode(value='a1')
b1 = GeneralTreeNode(value='b1')
b2 = GeneralTreeNode(value='b2')
a1.set_child(b1)
b1.set_parent(a1)
b1.set_right(b2)
b2.set_left(b1)

a1.get_child().get_right().get_value()
>>>> 'b2'
```